# Complete separation of logistic regression data

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I've been running some large logistic regression models in SAS, which take 4+ hours to converge. Recently however I acquired access to a Hadoop cluster and can use Python to fit the same models much faster (something more like 10-15 minutes).

Problematically, I have some complete/quasi-complete separation of data points in my data which results in failure to converge; I was using the FIRTH command in SAS to produce robust parameter estimates despite that, but there seems to be no equivalent option for Python, either in sklearn or statsmodels (I'm mostly using the latter).

Is there another way to get around this problem in Python?

Comment: please mention what your data is and what you want. Code conversion or code equivalents are very difficult to answer.

Comment: Unless you have prior information that your problem domain is best represented by a logistic regression model, you might consider an alternate formulation, namely that each class is represented by a Gaussian blob p(x|c_k) for each class k = 0, 1, etc. Then the posterior class probability is just p(c_k|x) via Bayes' rule. The surfaces of equal p(c_k|x) are planes, as they are in logistic regression, when the covariances are equal. More generally, the surfaces of equal p(c_k|x) are conic sections, when covariances are unequal. If you just need a classification model, it's worth considering.

Comment: To the extent that the Gaussian blobs overlap in density (i.e. the available data are not too far away from each other, relative to the diameter of each blob), there will be a smooth gradient from one class to the other, so you won't have a numerical problem even if the data points are separated. Unless, as I was saying, the classes of points are widely separated. In that case, you might add a constant to each dimension of the per-class covariance, to make them overlap; this amounts to a regularization term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no Firth penalization available in Python. Statsmodels has an open issue but nobody is working on it at the moment.

As alternative it would be possible to use a different kind of penalization, e.g. as available in sklearn or maybe statsmodels.

The other option is to change the observed response variable. Firth can be implemented by augmenting the dataset. However, I don't know of any recipe or prototype for this in Python.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3561

Statsmodels has ongoing work on penalization but currently the emphasis is on feature/variable selection (elastic net, SCAD) and quadratic penalization for generalized additive models GAM, especially for splines.

Firth uses data dependent penalization which does not fit the generic penalization framework where the penalization structure is a data independent "prior".

Answer (score 0):

Conditional likelihood is another way to work around perfect separation.  This is in a Statsmodels PR that is basically ready to use:

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/5304